# Could overload happen between template functions?

Tags: c++, overloading

If I design like this

```
template<class T>
void func(int i, T t) {
    i = i * 2;
    cout << "int change into " << i << "when t is " << t << endl;
}
template<class T>
void func(string s, T t) {
    cout << "string size is " << s.size() << "when t is " << t << endl;
}
```

and they works by invoking like

```
func<int>(1, 1);      --------> case 1
func<string>(1, "a"); --------> case 2
func<int>("a", 2);    --------> case 3
```

But in my case, template functions(between case 1 and 3) are used to deal with overload on the first parameter, and function overloads(between case 2 and 3) are in the same use but on the second parameter.
So it seems a bit odd to me that is there any redundancy in my function design?
Is my design valid and efficient?

Comment: This question seems more suitable for a review site; https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *"Could overload happen between template functions?..."* Yes

Comment: `func<string>("a",1);` will not compile.

Comment: @Jason, it looks totally *un*suitable for [codereview.se].  Example code is specifically outside its scope.

Comment: Notice that you could use directly `func(1, 1); func(1, "a"); func(a, 2);`.

Comment: I see a bunch of code that looks valid, and then you go on to describe hypothetical code, but I dont understand the description. Could you try also adding the invalid hypothetical code?

Answer (score 2):

This design is valid and follows the concept of function **overloading** in `C++`. Function overloading allows multiple functions with the same name but with different parameters to exist in a single program.

In this design, the first **template function func** takes an `int` and a
`generic type T`

as parameters, and the second template function takes a `string` and a `generic type T`.

It is efficient in that it allows the same function name to be used for different purposes based on the types of the parameters being passed, making the code more readable and maintainable.

However, in *case 3*, where you are passing a `string` as the first parameter and an int as the second parameter, both functions are considered equally valid candidates by the compiler, causing an ***ambiguity error***. To resolve this, you may need to either ***explicitly cast the string to an int*** or ***make the func templates more specific to avoid this type of ambiguity***.